# jquery - How to highlight a menu link when clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu with links. The links are placed inside a table. Each link is placed in a `<td>`. I want to change the background color of the `<td>` when its active. How am I gonna do it in jquery?

Here is the link to my code: http://jsfiddle.net/DdG8m/.

My problem is that if one the links is clicked the background color of the whole table changes. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code directly in the question, not only on a linked address.

Comment: Why is that a table?  http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the current element and not all elements matching your selector.

```
$("#mainMenu td").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
});
```

I´d also recommend you to use CSS classes instead of setting the CSS properties this way.

That would be something like;

```
$("#mainMenu td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

together with;

```
#mainMenu td.selected {
  background-color: #EDEDED;
}
```

**EDIT**

The psuedo selector `:visited` should only be used on links (`a`) and you should not use `table`s more than you really need to.

Created a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmcZJ/)** that uses an `ul` list instead of the table and `display: block` on links to fill the entire parent `li` element.

I´m also using [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to not follow the link as this probably would reload the page and not include the class for the selected/active link. If you want to follow the link and have the page reload you should use server side code to render that HTML.

```
$("#mainMenu a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Don´t follow the link
    $("#mainMenu a").removeClass('selected'); // Remove class on all menu items
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // Add class to current menu item
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class called `.highlight` and set it with the desired background color, then just add/remove the class accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/DdG8m/4/

```
$(function() {
    $('#mainMenu td').click(function(e) {
        $('#mainMenu td').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

​**note:** you will need to use `!important` on your `.highlight` class to override any default ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainMenu td").click(function() {
        $("#mainMenu td").css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
    });

});
​
```

That will change all tds in the table. Instead use `$(this)` inside your function to select the element that triggered the click event.

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainMenu td").click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
    });

});
​
```

To make the other ones revert back, use the `siblings()` selector to select all tds except the clicked one.

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainMenu td").click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#EDEDED')
        .siblings().css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but how am I gonna make it return to its original background color after I selected another one.

Comment: I got it now. This is my trick $(function() {
 $("#mainMenu td").click(function() {
  $("#mainMenu td").css('background-color', '#FAFAFA');
  $(this).css('background-color', '#EDEDED');
 });
});

Comment: YOur trick is better than mine. What I did was I changed everything to the original background color and proceeded to changing the selected one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('td').click(function() {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#EDEDED');
    });
});
```