# jQuery - How to highlight default menu link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this answer to highlight active links:

[jquery - How to highlight a menu link when clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597135/jquery-how-to-highlight-a-menu-link-when-clicked)

Is there a way to have one of the links highlighted by default when a user visits the page?

In this example, the word "All" would be highlighted in the alphabetical navigation:

https://acm.tru.ca/Page18490.aspx

The highlight would then move as the user clicks on other letters.

We're using jQuery but don't necessarily have to use it in this instance.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will highlight the `a` with class `alpha` and id `default` on page load:

```
$(function(){
    $('a[class=alpha][id=default]').addClass('highlight');
});
```